# swift immutable expression

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting the following error and I am unsure how to solve this.

> Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '[News].Type'

my code.
I was following the following video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtO5QT2D_H8
The only difference is No image in my cell.

The line in question is

> var tempNews = [News] = []

```
//
//  NewsViewController.swift
//  DRN1
//
//  Created by Russell Harrower on 26/11/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 Russell Harrower. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class NewsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var news: [News] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
        news = createArray()
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func createArray() -> [News] {
        //var tempNews = [News] = []
        var tempNews = [News] = []


        let news1 = News(title: "Hello")
        let news2 = News(title: "how")
        let news3 = News(title: "You")

        tempNews.append(news1)
        tempNews.append(news2)
        tempNews.append(news3)

        return tempNews
    }




  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "News"

          //     let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
            //    controller.player = player

                // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
          //      present(controller, animated: false) {
           //       player.play()
           //     }


  }

}


extension NewsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return news.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let newsa = news[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell") as! NewsCell
        cell.setNews(news: newsa)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly in the video did you find that code? Could it be that you just copied it wrongly?

Comment: Next time you get a simple compilation error, take some time and check the code and try to spot what is wrong instead. I mean you had almost the same declaration earlier in the file but correctly written so you know what the right syntax is

Comment: `var news = ["Hello", "how", "You"].map(News.init)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
var tempNews = [News]()
```

Or

```
var tempNews: [News] = []
```

Also it's better to

```
func createArray() -> [News] { 
    return [News(title: "Hello") , News(title: "how") , News(title: "You")]
}
```

Comment: Or `var tempNews: [News] = []` which is what they were going for but used an `=` instead of `:`.

Comment: `News(title:` `News(title`: `News(title:` why not simply  `["Hello", "how", "You"].map(News.init)` ?

Comment: Btw you should vote those kind of questions as typo

Comment: @LeoDabus ah, I didn't know "typo" was an option for vote to close. Thanks